# WordPress opens js files as a catalog. Path is right

Tags: javascript

When I import external js file everything is okay.. no matter if I import it by `<script>` tag or by wp_register_script function but when i try to import local file everything crashes. Firstly I had doubts about path I entered so I've opened Web Inspector in Opera and compare path I've entered with real path. The same. Unfortunately WordPress doesn't load script and what is really weird when I try to open given path in Web Inspector... It opens main site with given file address.. for example...

first-base address:

```
localhost/wordpress
```

adress of js file:

```
localhost/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/js/my-file.js
```

result of entering above link:

```
localhost/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/js/my-file.js/
```

and main site...

If I attach custom code trough plugin all code is visible on the top of the site as a plain text. Any ideas? I've read many of articles on attaching javascript files and finally .. I gave up.

Comment: Two things. 1) there's a typo in the path, it should be `wp-includes`. 2) You should never put your own files in the `wp-includes` folder as they can be lost on upgrade and generally don't belong there. Instead, include it in a theme, custom plugin, or mu-plugin.

Comment: Also, adding more info about what "crashes" and "catalog" mean may help. It's not really clear from what you've written so far.

Comment: wordpress doesn't "load" javascript file, only the browser does. If the URL is correct then it means that your webserver/htaccess is not configured correctly to serve JS files.

Comment: @mrwweb good point. I had not thought about it. Thank you. Crashes mean it just doesn't works :) and catalog means that when I open my javascript file it looks like simple adress...like permalinks set to /%category%/%postname%/ but with that difference that no matter what you type in there's always main site showing up  - like I wrote. Whatever u wrote after "wordpress" because if u write for example localhost/deadsite then u get normal 404 error and under the localhost I can insert JS without any problems.So there must be problem about WordPress.Like Mark said.Thank You Both for your replies!

Comment: it's not off-topic because problem was caused by WordPress, not PHP... I completely don't understand ... Given answer helped me (I comment answer to confirm).. so what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve your problem while moving toward a best practice while you're at it by using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). This will likely solve your issues because it's domain agnostic.

Start by moving your JS file(s) to a `/js/` folder in your [child] theme or custom plugin. Then load your script like this... (snippets copied and adpated from Codex page).

### Theme

Goes into `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue script from theme
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-file.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

### Child Theme

Goes into `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue script from child theme
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-file.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

### Plugin

Goes into a plugin file. For this, there'd probably only be one.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts from a plugin
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', plugins_url( '/js/my-file.js', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

This will then work on an domain so long as the file is there.

Comment: I put my files into the /themedirectory/js/ and everything is ok! And I found solution (confirmed your) .
From Codex:

    JavaScript will work within WordPress. It can be used within WordPress template files in WordPress Themes or Child Themes.

And only there! It's probably security action but it's only my speculation.
Thanks guys for supporting me. especially you @mrwweb.